# SetupDiCallClassInstaller returns false

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, usb, wmi

I want to enable and disable a specific USB disk, I've found about this method:

```
 public static bool StateChange(bool Enable, int SelectedItem, IntPtr DevInfo)
        {
            bool result = false;
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA(); ;
            devInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
            if (true == SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DevInfo, SelectedItem, devInfoData))
            {
                SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS pcp = new SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS(); ;
                pcp.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER));
                pcp.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
                pcp.Scope = DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL;

                pcp.StateChange = (Enable ? DICS_ENABLE : DICS_DISABLE);
                if (true == SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(DevInfo, devInfoData, pcp, Marshal.SizeOf(pcp)))
                {
                    if (true == SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE, DevInfo, devInfoData))
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

But it fails when calling :
   SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE, DevInfo, devInfoData) (returns false)

Is it because I'm running windows 7 x64 ?

Comment: On the row after your call to SetupDiCallClassInstaller do a call to the function GetLastError
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx) and you'll get an ErrorCode value that may tell you something about what went wrong.

Comment: if (true == SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE, DevInfo, devInfoData))
                        {
                            result = true;
                        }
                        int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        System.Console.WriteLine(lastError); It just prints 0. I have tested the application on a 32 bit Win7 and the disable worked, but I can't enable it now, I plug in the usb stick and it doesn't show up as mounted, although I can notice its presence using the application.

Comment: the way I got the GetlastError method is here : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.getlasterror

Comment: I would think that Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); is the same thing and the way to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), .."for certain DIF requests, the caller must be a member of the Administrators group". Have you tested the credentials?